# tiki-wiki: How to batch import categorized articles from a CSV file

Tags: tiki-wiki

Importing categories as a CSV file is OK in tiki-wiki, But how to import categorized articles to the system. Tiki supports media wiki and word press importing, While my data base has another format.

> 1. Is there any module for CSV upload/import?
> 2. Is there any flexible migration-like script to import articles?

In case that both of answers are **NO**, would you please give me a clue to write down the proper code to import articles directly to data base.
I went through understanding database, But I think accessing to database directly should be my last choice!

Comment: Just as a clarification, do you want to import into the article feature or as wiki pages?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the exact difference and future consequences of selecting to import as article or page!

Comment: One time publication / news -> articles - Collaboration, long-term content evolution -> wiki

Answer (score 1):

For custom import jobs, you can use [Tiki's profiles](http://profiles.tiki.org). The profiles are a YAML-based format. While it is not the primary use for them, it might be the easiest way to perform what you want to do.

Normally, you need to place the profile in a repository to execute it, but there is a developer option to load content from a textarea. You can simply prepare your YAML definition and paste it in there.

Categorizing elements through the database could be harder than it seems as many tables are involved.

Comment: SO I should go through this steps: 1- importing with Tiki's profiles. 2- Setting article's categories later in db (may be very hard). Am I right? Isn't really any official module, plugin, script?

Comment: Tiki supports batch upload for categories. Do you suggest import categories via profiles?

Comment: You don't have to, but it is an option. You can simply prepare your import, test it on a clean installation, fix issues and re-test until you are ready, then apply it to the real site. If everything is in the profile, you have fewer steps to iterate over while testing.